# How to extract data from file on an FTP server without downloading it all in R? - encoding error?

Tags: r, ftp, rcurl

I am trying to get a large dataset (3+ GB) from the following server:

ftp://podaac-ftp.jpl.nasa.gov/allData/ghrsst/data/L4/GLOB/JPL/MUR

I know `RCurl` is a good package for getting data from FTP. The file is a compressed netcdf file. I need to uncompress it to read it into R using `ncdf4`. It's compressed as `bz2`.

Importantly, the file is larger than I want on my hard drive, so saving a copy locally is not an ideal option. How can I access data on the file without saving a copy to my disk first?

Here's my attempt so far:

```
library(RCurl); library(ncdf4)
d = getURL('ftp://podaac-ftp.jpl.nasa.gov/allData/ghrsst/data/L4/GLOB/JPL/MUR/2015/144/20150524-JPL-L4UHfnd-GLOB-v01-fv04-MUR.nc.bz2')
d = bzfile(d, open = 'r')
d = nc_open(d)
```

But I'm stuck at this cryptic error after the first line:

```
Error in curlPerform(curl = curl, .opts = opts, .encoding = .encoding) : 
  embedded nul in string: 'BZh91AY&SY¦ÁÀÉ\0033[ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿáåÏ\035\017)³îÎ\u009dÍØcn]sw7½ÎkÜÞõï=uÎ×¯v]ìçn\u009dÎn½îê·±Þìê÷wS­M\u008có·+ÎçW¹Ý=Ù×¹\u009cÎ³­ÜëÞs½ÛN¹²w;\u009buÍÝ]{·k^çuªnìº-³6«[+Üå;\033m»Û½ow:w¹ïo{uyîî\u00937¬\\Æµl¶½\u009dÖVìç¯{ÎõïoSm]Ý×\u009eî\u008dæî®î®î\vÛÕïgW\036î®wqîÝ\\ïw«6½Þï\036Ýrë§=¬Fg·\\íåÔÙº÷gu·3\u009bKmÛ\027­Þ»\u0092îî\016îêwwm»\u009b­·s;MÞÁ½½­ÎóÍso^»q¯o;k\033iµ\u009bÛuyÝÞní5w:ï]ÓuÎo[«\033:åÞvEÜíÎç½ÝË­\u009eìQNöÔ\u008e\u0094vmÝÈ¯g»e lÍ^\u008a©'
```

It seems to be an encoding issue based on other similar problems but I tried both `.encoding = 'UTF-8'` and `.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'` as shown in the `getURL()` documentation but neither work.
I've seen other answers to problems like this but they all seem to involve editing the source file. I don't have write access to this file, however. Any help?

Comment: How can this be? You would rather wait to download 3GB several times from the net rather than store it locally on your disk - is that correct? How do you intend to access it if you don't want to store it?

Comment: Sorry, clarification: there are multiple files that are 3 GB each. Not looking to download the same file multiple times. Is there no way to only download a subset of the data to my hard drive? I only need about 100 MB of the 3 GB of data from each file. Is there no way to search the file on the server, and download only the subset of data I want?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `httr` for this

```
library("httr")
library("ncdf4")
url <- 'ftp://podaac-ftp.jpl.nasa.gov/allData/ghrsst/data/L4/GLOB/JPL/MUR/2015/144/20150524-JPL-L4UHfnd-GLOB-v01-fv04-MUR.nc.bz2'
res <- GET(url, write_disk(basename(url)))
# uncompress - I used OSX's default compression tool
nc_open(sub("\\.bz2", "", res$request$output$path))
```

the only step i didn't sort out programatically is un-compressing the bz2 file, just did that with OSX's default tool

Comment: Does this technique write the data to my hard drive? The data file is over 3 GB and I'll be doing this a number of times, so saving the data locally is not an option.

Comment: Yes, `httr::write_disk()` writes to disk instead of saving to an object in R.  You can simply cleanup after you've read into R, just `unlink("filename")`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much at all about `R`, but you should be able to do this with curl in FTP mode by changing the output to stdout rather than a local filename and then using `bz2` to uncompress the file you want from its standard input.

So, for example, I can do this:

```
curl --output - --user user:password 'ftp://127.0.0.1/somefile.bz2' | bz2 ...
```

Maybe you can start that from within `R`? Or make a fifo with:

```
mkfifo fifo
curl ....
```

and then read from the file called `fifo` in `R`.

Or maybe `R` has a `system()` command, and you could do:

```
system('mkfifo fifo; curl ..... | bz2 .... > fifo &')
```

and then read from the file called `fifo` in `R`.